# Add several widgets dynamically PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, widget

I designed a simple download manager on qt designer and would like to add several widgets(specifically the lower portion of the window the one containing the progress bar and the pushbuttons)[image]

My question is, Is it possible? If so, How can I implement such a design? and if someone can direct me to an article or a website that has answered that kind of question before?

Comment: Please consider that asking for suggestions, tutorial and references is considered off-topic. Also read the documentation about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and the existing classes to understand how to dynamically add items to existing layouts.

Comment: Is that a QScrollArea that is a container for widgets you want to dynamically add? In any case, it looks like that container has a grid layout. In Designer, if you look at the Object Inspector, click on your container. Then in the Property Editor, scroll all the way down until you get the Layout section. Use the layoutName in your Python Code to add new items (e.g. `self.gridLayout2.addwidget(....)`. You can also get a reference to the container's layout using in code using the layout() method, e.g. `layout = MyContainer.layout()`

Answer (score 1):

You can add widgets (and layouts) dynamically to any layout. Just create instance and call `addWidget()`

```py
button = QPushButton()
ui.some_layout.addWidget(button)
```